# Show PubMed RSS feed with google feed api

Tags: javascript, google-feed-api

I am trying to add a RSS feed to my website using Google feeds.  The problem is that it clips the number of entries.  I only see 4 entries, but when i curl the RSS i see 28 entries.   How can I have it load the rest of the entries.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/erss.cgi?rss_guid=1zYrsILa0sOsmYw2yBRKaeHt9hnGCeczWTLrGvu39KX1g_ZMyr");
    feed.load(function(result) {
        alert(result.feed.entries);
        if (!result.error) {
            var container = document.getElementById("feed");
            var text = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                text += "<a href='" + entry.link + "'>" + entry.title + "</a><br />" + entry.description + "<br /><br />";
            }
            container.innerHTML = text;
        }
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
```

and html

```
<div id="feed">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the option for the number of entries to retrieve thusly:

```
feed.setNumEntries(50);
```

The [Feed API documentation](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide) indicates that the default is 4. (Look under "Setting the number of feed entries".)

Comment: I'm embarrassed I even asked the question.  I thought that was only to limit the returned, I did not realize there was a default limitation in place.  Thanks!